# Can i use Meteor.js WITHOUT any React and Angular and Blaze? I want use my own library

Tags: angular, reactjs, user-interface, blaze

Can i use Meteor.js **WITHOUT** any React and Angular and Blaze? I want use my own library

Comment: Does anyone know how to disable the hated React and Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need run this command

```
meteor remove blaze-html-templates
```

it remove Blaze